# I'm having difficult time referencing the correct DOM node via Javascript. What is the issue?

Tags: javascript, dom, reference, element

Here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write(document.getElementsByTagName("select").value);
</script>
<form>
<select value="slct">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
</form>
```

The rest has been redacted for brevity. I've tried using "nodeValue" and "value" at the end of the string without success. When I cut out the value it outputs "[object]".

I know I'm likely missing something obvious, but I can't seem to get the referencing of elements down. I'm trying to develop a checkbox which enables a dropdown box, but I keep getting stuck at this jumping off point.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0].value`?

Answer (score 5):

1. The element doesn't exist at the time you call `document.getElementsByTagName`. Move the script to after the select element, or delay it (e.g. by making it a function you call `onload` … except you are using the (ugly, problematic, best avoided) `document.write` which doesn't play nice after the load event fires.
2. `document.getElementsByTagName` returns a NodeList, not a single DOM node, so it won't have a value property
3. `value` is not well supported cross-browser on select elements. Get the selectedIndex, use that to get the selected option element, then get the value of that element.

Comment: Thank you so much for your speedy response! I've been tinkering with it some more and I added the "onclick" to get rid of the "document.write", but I'm still encountering errors. I input the "alert((document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0].value));" to output the value of the select. This is outputting the value of select.child[0]. When I use the length function it correctly calls three children elements. What's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the getElemenstByTagName returns a node list.
try

`document.write(document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0].value`

Assuming that is the first select in your document.  You can also use`getElementById` if you add an id attribute to the select.

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByTagName()` returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/NodeList) of elements, not a single element. To retrieve the `.value` you must address one of the elements (as if an array), e.g.

```
document.write(document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0].value);
```

Note this returns a list even if there is only one `select` element on your page.

Comment: Not an array.  A NodeList which is slightly different from an array in that it is "live". If you remove one of the selects from the dom it will also be removed from the list.

Comment: A NodeList doesn't have all the methods you can expect to find on an Array either.

Comment: Thanks both, I was already in the process of editing when you commented.